# Python/Tkinter: need code to define / import a widget as a class outside root window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been wrestling for a very long time with the issue of creating a Tkinter gui in modular fashion using classes. While there are many examples on this site - and believe me, I have read them all - they have all been too complex for me to understand. In particular, I could not work out how the imported modules could 'talk to' functions in the main application. I have finally had a eureka moment - I created a class in a module that defines a root window and a button. Then, I wrote a main python file that imports the root window / button module, and tests interactions between the imported module and the main app. All of those tests were successful, which is huge progress for me, as far as it goes. Here is the module code, saved as 'fmod.py':

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # configure the root window
    self.title('Tkinter titlebar title')
    self.geometry('300x50')

    # create button within root window
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Click Me')
    self.button.pack()
```

Here is the python file written to import the module, and test all the interactions I was interested in understanding:

```
import tkinter as tk

# import module
import fmod

# create gui root window as an instance of imported MainWindow class
MainWin = fmod.MainWindow()

# define a local function for testing purposes
def ButtonClicked():
  print("Button clicked")
  
# alter attributes of imported root/button from within this file
MainWin.geometry("700x400")
MainWin.config(bg = "yellow")
MainWin.button.config(bg="lightblue")

# add a new widget to root from within this file
NewLabel = tk.Label(MainWin,text="Label")
NewLabel.pack()

# connect an imported widget to the above local function
MainWin.button.config(command=ButtonClicked)

# mainloop
MainWin.mainloop()
```

As mentioned, all of the tests in the above code worked successfully. The question is this: I would rather have the MainWindow class define the root window and nothing else. So rather than including the button in that code, I'd like to write another entirely separate class that simply defines a button, which could be imported into my app separately. Would anyone be kind enough to help me write that code? I tried copying code from the MainWindow class, and it worked, but it opened an entirely new window (probably because of the init / super init code, which I do not fully understand, and don't really need to understand at the moment - it works, and I'm fine with that). I want code for a simple button that I could import into the main app, as a widget, and that I could place in the MainWin window inside the app.

Comment: `class MyButton(tk.Button):`

Comment: It is better to post what you have tried on defining another button class and the issue you came across.

Comment: Rather ask such question in the [tkinter chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter) since these question already has answers and mostly not very welcomed on [so]

Answer (score 0):

You can define the class in a separate module and then import it, but you will still want to initiate the button inside of your main window like you are doing now.  After all the button does belong on the window.

To create a button class it would be similar to how you created the MainWindow...

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ... do something

    def buttonClicked(self, *args):
        print("Button Clicked")
```

Then you could just leave you mainwindow the way it is except switch out the class for your class.  I also suggest moving a lot of your logic that is in the global scope inside of your MainWindow, and minimizing your use of the global scope as much as possible.  For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from mybuttonmodule import MyButton

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # configure the root window
    self.title('Tkinter titlebar title')
    self.geometry('300x50')

    # create button within root window
    self.button = MyButton(self, text='Click Me')
    self.button.pack()
    self.button.config(command=self.button.buttonClicked)
    self.newlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Label")
    self.newlabel.pack()
    self.geometry("700x400")
    self.config(bg = "yellow")
    self.button.config(bg="lightblue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MainWindow()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you very much. Many mysteries solved...finally.